# Manipular o evento Scroll em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde,

Eu tenho uma Navbar que inicia transparente eu seto isso via query:

```
$( "nav" ).css('border', 'none', 'important');
$("#hamburguer").css('background-color', 'transparent', 'important');
```

Até aqui beleza, mas quando eu descer quero que ela volte as propriedades normais do bootstrap, e quando eu der o scroll pra cima ela voltaria a ser transparente. Alguma sugestão? Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir o `style` ao rolar pra cima.

Ao rolar pra baixo, retire o `style` deixando assim a tag `nav` com o que foi definido na folha de estilos.

Usei `style = border: 1px solid` só pra facilitar a visualização no exemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {$('nav').attr('style', 'border: 1px solid');});

var st = 0;
$(document).on('scroll', function(event){

   var st2 = $(this).scrollTop();
   
   if (st2 > st){   
       
    if ($('nav').attr('style') !== undefined) {
       
    $('nav').removeAttr('style');
    
    }
       
       
   } else {
      
      if ($('nav').attr('style') === undefined) {
      
      $('nav').attr('style', 'border: 1px solid');
      
      }
      
   }
   
   st = st2;
   
  
});
```

```css
html, body {height: 400px; background-color: #e5e5e5}

nav {position: fixed}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html><body>

<nav>nav</nav>

</body></html>
```